# Seaborn showing x-tick labels overlapping

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I am trying to make a box plot that looks like this.
[image]

Now, there are a lot of tickmarks that I do not need and truly do not show any additional information. 
The code I am using is the following:

```
plot=sns.boxplot(y=MSE, x=Sim, 
                   width=0.5,
                   palette='colorblind')
plot=sns.stripplot(y=MSE, x=Sim, 
                  jitter=True, 
                  marker='o', 
                  alpha=0.15,
                  color='black')
plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
```

Where MSE and SIM are two numpy arrays of 400 elements each.

I reviewed some solutions that use locator_params and set_xticklabels. However, I want to know:

- why this happen and,
- is there a simple transformation in the MSE and SIM arrays to solve this?

I hope my questions are clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very sure what you have as Sim, if it is an array of floats, then they are converted to categorical before plotting. The thing you can do, since the labels are not useful, is to use a range of values thats as long as the y-values.

With that, it still overlaps a lot because you are trying to fit 400 x ticks onto the x-axis, and the font size are set by default to be something readable. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))

MSE = [np.random.normal(0,1,10) for i in range(100)]
Sim = np.arange(len(MSE))
g = sns.boxplot(y=MSE, x=Sim, width=0.5,palette='colorblind',ax=ax)
```

[image]

You can set the font size to be smaller and they don't overlap but I guess its hardly readable:

[image]

So like you said in your case, they are not useful, you can do:

```
ax.set(xticks=Sim[0::10])
```

Comment: Amazing, this is the reason _if it is an array of floats, then they are converted to categorical_ Thank you very much!  Is there a better way to plot an array of floats so it is not converted to categorical variables?

Comment: The x-axis is converted to categorical.. but not the y-values.. So you use a numerical array to plot, as I did above? Hope I did not misunderstand you